# Redis Time Series Issue

Tags: php, node.js, redis, redistimeseries

- Inside docker i have installed redis stack server and i am using nodejs express api to test redis time series command however it always throws an error **unknown command "TS.CREATE" or "TS.ADD" ** but inside **redis-cli** redis-timeseries works perfectly.

i also tried in php but same error unknown command

This is my nodejs code

```
app.get('/add', async function (req, res, next) {
try {
    const client = createClient()
    await client.connect()

    const created = await client.ts.create('temperature', {
        RETENTION: 86400000,
        ENCODING: TimeSeriesEncoding.UNCOMPRESSED,
        DUPLICATE_POLICY: TimeSeriesDuplicatePolicies.BLOCK,
    });

    if (created === 'OK') {
        console.log('Created timeseries.');
    } else {
        console.log('Error creating timeseries :(');
        process.exit(1);
    }
} catch (error) {
    next(error)
}
```

});

and this is my php code

both gives same error

Comment: Is it possible that you are accessing from your code another Redis instance - not the Redis Stack instance? Usually, this error suggests that RedisTimeSeries is not available. RedisTimeSeries is part of Redis Stack, but not of Redis (unless you installed this module manually).

Comment: Did you use the [official Redis Stack docker image](https://redis.io/docs/install/install-stack/docker/)?